# <h:form> within <ui:repeat> not entirely working, only the last <h:form> is processed

Tags: forms, jsf-2, uirepeat

I will like to edit a list of items in the same page. Each item should be edited using a separate form. I am creating a h:form within ui:repeat. Only when the last form is submitted, the user input is applied to the managed bean. For all other forms, user input is not applied to the model.

```
@ManagedBean
public class Controller {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("TestWeb");
    private List<Customer> customerList;

    public List<Customer> getCustomerList() {
        if (customerList == null) {
            customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
            customerList.add(new Customer("Daffy Duck", "daffy@example.com"));                          
            customerList.add(new Customer("Bugs Bunny", "bugs@example.com"));       
            customerList.add(new Customer("Samity Sam", "sam@example.com"));
        }
        return customerList;
    }
    public String updateCustomer(Customer c) {
        logger.info("Updating: " + c.getName());
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the view, I have

```
<ui:repeat var="c" value="#{controller.customerList}">
<h:form>
  <h3>Edit Customer</h3>
  Name: <h:inputText value="#{c.name}"/><br/>
  E-mail: <h:inputText value="#{c.email}"/><br/>
  <h:commandButton value="Update"
    action="#{controller.updateCustomer(c)}"/>
</h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

I search for hours without any solution. What will be the correct way to do this? I can hack it by using a single form and using a ui:repeat within it. But there are many issues with that and I will rather not take that route. Thanks.

Comment: You can achieve this by wrapping only the `<h:commandButton/>` with the `<h:form/>`.

Comment: @kolossus, are you sure? I tried wrapping the command button in a form. That didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh? In retrospect, that figures, as at the time that the markup is being rendered, the argument you're supplying to the `updateCustomer` method would've been set to the last value. You should just supply the selected value to the backing bean using an `<f:param/>` instead, maybe passing just the id of the entity. I've used this before so I'm sure it works. Be advised though, it poses a security risk passing an Id back and forth like so. You might want to secure the parameter somehow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bug in state saving of `<ui:repeat>` in Mojarra. There are several similar issue reports at http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES, among others [issue 2243](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2243).

You have basically 2 options: use another iterating component (e.g. `<c:forEach>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<t:dataList>`, `<p:dataList>`, etc), or replace Mojarra by MyFaces (the `<ui:repeat>` in this construct works properly in there).

Comment: I have reworked my solution using <c:forEach> and everything is now working. Thanks!