# Valuechange Listener inside ui:repeat only works for the last repeated component

Tags: jsf, uirepeat, valuechangelistener

I'm using JSF and Glassfish. I have in a ui:repeat several h:inputtextarea where I have a valuechange Listener. The problem is that the valuechangelistener only fires for the last component. here is my code.

The answerhandler return a list of Answerentities (JPA) which define the content. The answerhandler itself is a ManagedBean which is my controller. 
I know that the code is a little redundant but that's not the matter here. 
The valuechangelistener should be fired if a form is submited --> the button "save" is clicked. but it is only fired for the last repeated form.

First xhtml file:

```
<ui:repeat var="a" value="#{answerHandler.answerByCreated}">                                    
   <h:form>
   <h:inputTextarea readonly="#{!a.equals(answerHandler.tobeEdited)}" 
      id="showacontent" value="#{a.content}"  class="form-control questiontextarea" 
      rows="8" valueChangeListener="#{answerHandler.acontentChanged}"
      pt:maxlength="2500"/>                                     
   <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" >
     <h:commandButton action="#{answerHandler.setEditable(a)}" rendered="#{answerHandler.canEditAnswer(a) and !answerHandler.isEdit}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" />
     <h:commandButton action="#{answerHandler.cancel()}" rendered="#{answerHandler.isEdit and a.equals(answerHandler.tobeEdited)}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel" />
     <h:commandButton action="#{answerHandler.saveChanges(a)}" rendered="#{answerHandler.isEdit and a.equals(answerHandler.tobeEdited)}" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
   </div>                  
   </h:form>

</ui:repeat>
```

And here the answerhandler class with the called methods

```
public void acontentChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
    if (e != null) {
        System.out.println("change");
        oldcontent = e.getOldValue().toString();
        tobeEdited.setContent(e.getNewValue().toString());
        saveChanges(tobeEdited);
    }

}

public void saveChanges(Answer a) {
    if (canEditAnswer(a)) {
        a.setEdited(new Date());
        aManager.edit(a);
        disableEditable();
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

**EDIT**

I wrapped ui:repeat in a h:form and it works now. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/3773914/tt-dev for your comment, it really helped me out. Could you maybe explain why it works when h:form wraps ui:repeat?

Comment: your html mark-up seems incorrect, there is no start of `h:form`. also, take the form outside of `ui:repeat` and try again please.

Comment: well i shortened the code a little bit in order to make it more easy for you guys

Comment: Where did you start the `<h:form>` outside upwards the `<ui:repeat>`? This will generate invalid HTML markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i actually cannot remember the exact reason behind this but, when you render multiple forms in a repeater component, just the last rendered one submits requests.

so the solution is to place the `h:form` out of `ui:repeat`.

ps: using multiple forms on page, which are not generated inside a repeater works fine.

edit: seems to be a bug, which is mentioned here by BalusC: [<h:form> within <ui:repeat> not entirely working, only the last <h:form> is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808878/uiform-within-uirepeat-not-working)

Comment: `ui:repeater`? It is `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: @Tiny sorry, corrected that. thanks for the warning.

Comment: Oh okay thanks. I'm sorry when I google ui:repeat and valuechangelistener I didn't find a solution for it.