# <pe:fluidGrid> not updating var in second iteration of <p:dataList>

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I have a `pe:fluidGrid` within `p:dataList` wich reads elements from a hashmap. 
I used to hava `ui:repeat` instead of p:dataList butt changed it due to this post: [<h:form> within <ui:repeat> not entirely working, only the last <h:form> is processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808878/hform-within-uirepeat-not-entirely-working-only-the-last-hform-is-proc)

My Problem now is: that the inner fluidGrid is not correctly updating its `var data`.

```
<p:dataList var="pdi" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems.keySet()}" id="all" varStatus="loop" type="none" >

        <p:panel id="panel" header="#{pdi.getFragmentDefinition().getFragmentName()}" style="margin-bottom:1em; width:100%;" >

            <pe:fluidGrid  id="fluidGrid" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi]}" var="data"
                           hGutter="20" vGutter="10"  widgetVar="fluidGridWdgt_#{loop.index}" >

                #{data.id} #{data.label}
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="stringValue"  id="txt_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        #{data.id}
                        <p:outputLabel for="txt" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().label} _ #{data.id}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:inputText id="txt" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().value}"/>
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="integerValue" id="int_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        #{data.id}
                        <p:outputLabel for="int" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().label} _ #{data.id}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:spinner id="int" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().value}" />
                </pe:fluidGridItem>
                <pe:fluidGridItem type="dateValue" id="cal_">
                    <div class="dynaFormLabel">
                        #{data.id}
                        <p:outputLabel for="cal" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().label} _ #{data.id}"/>
                    </div>
                    <p:calendar id="cal" value="#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().value}" showOn="button"/>

                </pe:fluidGridItem>

            </pe:fluidGrid>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataList>
```

[image: Ilustrating the problem]

Each Panel in the screenshot is created within the p:dataList. As you can see highlighted in red, The second panel starts with the last value of the first panel. The second panel is not complete du to a then occuring index out of bound exception (trying to access the 3rd index in a list of size 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently all i had to do was change
`#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi].get(data.id).getData().label}` to 
`#{FormGenerator.formItems[pdi][data.id].getData().label}`

Anyone got any insights in what the difference is?